# I cant echo Invalid as i use else statement

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I cant view Invalid, any suggestion to make it run?

```
    <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Strand</th>
    <th>Section</th>
</tr>   

<?php
 $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","search");
 $set=$_POST['search'];
 if ($set > 0) {
 $show="SELECT * FROM search_student WHERE fname='$set'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$show);

 while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { 
    echo  "<tr>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo $rows['fname'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo $rows['lname'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo $rows['strand'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo $rows['section'];
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "<tr>";
    echo "</br>";
 }
 }
```

The else statement here doesn't work

```
  else{
 echo "invalid";
 }

 ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: a simple help is a big one for a student like me

Comment: `While` doesn't have an `else` tree. Is that what the question is about? A little more effort on explaining what you wanted to accomplish wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: if $set >0 you'll never enter in the else condition

Comment: what im trying to do sir is to search a name that exist in the mysql database and it works just fine, it is just that it doesnt show the invalid sign even if i change it as a header? any recommendations sir @mario?

Comment: You could try `if ( !empty($_POST['search']) ) {` and move this before the `$set=$_POST['search'];` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { 
        echo  "<tr>";
        //etc

       }
     }
     else
     {
      echo "invalid";
     }
```

Comment: Some explanation (even if you may think it's obvious) helps any answer.  ( As I'm not sure how this fits with the current code where the if statement is `if ($set > 0) {`)

Comment: @Mario has already stated that "While doesn't have an else tree", hence the need to use `if-else`

Comment: Sorry - I did add (to my original comment) the if in the original code is `if ($set > 0) {`

Comment: it worked! Thanks alot, i just declared the variables show and result before the if statement so it will be declared first. THANKS ALOT